# Add additional question to faq about avoiding duplicates?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, faq-proposed

I am a new user to the Stack Exchange network.

I am making a proposal to add to the FAQ a Question: [How to avoid asking duplicate questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/145132/how-can-i-avoid-asking-duplicate-questions)

This will be especially useful to the new users (FAQ is supposed to help new users, I guess).

Please explain the following:

1. How to effectively search for an answer/question? (Please add the discussion [How do I search?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/searching))
2. Will asking a specific question about a system whose answer is in another question which deals with the general aspect of the system be considered a duplicate and closed? (Meaning question is not exactly a duplicate, but answer can be found by extensive reading of answers from other related questions)
3. Please add the question to the FAQ: [When will a question be considered a duplicate?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3000/at-what-point-does-a-question-become-a-duplicate) and [When it will be not considered a duplicate?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12182/when-is-a-duplicate-question-not-a-duplicate?rq=1)

This is not a duplicate of the question 'how to avoid asking duplicate questions' because this deals with adding that question to faq.

Comment: You are my favorite kind of new user. Welcome!

Comment: Why wouldn't we just add this question (and its answers) to the FAQ? [How can I avoid asking duplicate questions?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/145132/262755)

Comment: That is good, but please add “an improved search engine for se” too under the title how to search effectively to find what I want or something similar. That post really helped me to refine my search

Comment: This is not a duplicate.